# how to install wx python in python 310?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to install wx in python but after typeing `pip install WXPython`, it will tell me:

```
<module>                                                                                                                   
          from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping, Sequence                                                     
      ImportError: cannot import name MutableMapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\collections\__init__.py)                                                                         
      [end of output]                                                                                                   
    and at the end it will tell me: 
 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

I've fixed this problem but again after typeing the command `pip install WXPython` or `pip install wxpython`, it will give the following errors to me:

```
  Running setup.py install for wxpython ... -                                                                           
error:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                                   
  × Running setup.py install for wxpython did not run successfully.                                                     
      C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarn: ing: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'line cense_file' instead                                                                                                     
      Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                         File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1226, in __init__                                                                                                               raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)                                                               distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: No suitable Microsoft Visual C++ version found                              
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: No suitable Microsoft Visual C++ version found                           
error: legacy-install-failure
```

what should i doo to fix this problem?
my python version is 3.10.7 32 bit:
thanks

Comment: how and where did you get wxPython?

Comment: by using pip command, pip install WXPython

Comment: @esteerk, try to get it from wxpython web site...

Comment: warnings.warn(                                                                                                        
C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

Comment: I tryed this befor asking this questions, but my problem won't fixed: please help me to fix this problem: thanks

Comment: you are better off asking on the wxPython forum/ML I presume you are working with Windows 11? Please sign-up for wxPython forum and ask your question there.

Comment: I caant understand this, you are better off asking on the wxPython forum/ML: and I have windows 10 on my computer,  okay thanks

Comment: this is what I mean - https://discuss.wxpython.org/ Not too many wxPython devs come here and this is exactly the problem that needs to be dealt with the wxPython itself.